# How does alpha relate to C in Scikit-Learn's SGDClassifier?

Tags: svm, linear-model, scikit-learn, hyperparameter

I'm trying to get the same linear SVM classifier model by using Scikit-Learn's `SVC`, `LinearSVC` and `SGDClassifier` classes. I managed to do so (see the code below), but only by manually tweaking the `alpha` hyperparameter for the `SGDClassifier` class.

Both `SVC` and `LinearSVC` have the regularization hyperparameter `C`, but the `SGDClassifier` has the regularization hyperparameter `alpha`. The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svc) says that `C = n_samples / alpha`, so I set `alpha = n_samples / C`, but when I use this value, the `SGDClassifier` ends up being a very different model than the `SVC` and `LinearSVC` models. If I manually tweak the value of `alpha`, I can get all models to be approximately the same, but there should be a simple equation to find `alpha` given `C`. What is it?

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=0.15, random_state=42)

C = 5
alpha = len(X)/C  # alpha == 20

sgd_clf1 = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", alpha=alpha, n_iter=10000, random_state=42)
sgd_clf2 = SGDClassifier(loss="hinge", alpha=0.0007, n_iter=10000, random_state=42)
svm_clf = SVC(kernel="linear", C=C)
lin_clf = LinearSVC(loss="hinge", C=C)

X_scaled = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
sgd_clf1.fit(X_scaled, y)
sgd_clf2.fit(X_scaled, y)
svm_clf.fit(X_scaled, y)
lin_clf.fit(X_scaled, y)

print("SGDClassifier(alpha=20):     ", sgd_clf1.intercept_, sgd_clf1.coef_)
print("SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0007): ", sgd_clf2.intercept_, sgd_clf2.coef_)
print("SVC:                         ", svm_clf.intercept_, svm_clf.coef_)
print("LinearSVC:                   ", lin_clf.intercept_, lin_clf.coef_)
```

This code outputs:

```
SGDClassifier(alpha=20):      [-0.46597258] [[ 0.0283698  -0.03634389]]
SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0007):  [ 0.0422716] [[ 0.79608868 -1.48847539]]
SVC:                          [ 0.04569242] [[ 0.79788013 -1.48716383]]
LinearSVC:                    [ 0.04556911] [[ 0.79762806 -1.4866854 ]]
```

Note: to make the `LinearSVC` class output the same result as the `SVC` class, you have to center the inputs (eg. using the `StandardScaler`) since it regularizes the bias term (weird). You also need to set `loss="hinge"` since the default is `"squared_hinge"` (weird again).

So my question is: how does `alpha` *really* relate to `C` in Scikit-Learn? Looking at the equations, the documentation should be right, but in practice it is not. What's going on?

Comment: I got the feeling you should call SGDClassifier with 1/alpha (after your calculations). But this is just an empirical feeling looking at the default-value and the recommend grid-search range [10^1, ...10^-7]. Another matter: are you sure your SGDClassifiers converged (might be hard to check; and yes, you got a huge amount of iterations, but that should not really help in theory, if the learning-rate/learning-rate-schedule is bad)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @sascha. I tried 1/alpha, but it did not give the same result as SVC and LinearSVC. I am using the default learning schedule, which is supposed to guarantee convergence (if I understand correctly) provided the number of iterations is large enough (I put a huge value to be sure, but I get the same result with a smaller number of iterations).  This is so strange, and quite frustrating...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct scaling is `C_svc * n_samples = 1 / alpha_sgd` instead of `C_svc = n_samples / alpha_sgd`, the documentation seems to be incorrect.

In your example, it gives `alpha = 0.002`, and the results are similar with the `SVC` estimator's.

After a quick overview, it seems that the equivalence is:

`1. / C_svr` ~
`1. / C_svc` ~
`1. / C_logistic` ~
`alpha_elastic_net * n_samples` ~
`alpha_lasso * n_samples` ~
`alpha_sgd * n_samples` ~
`alpha_ridge`

---

**Note** that this is not a API-design failure, since scaling is more appropriate in some cases (e.g. with L1 regularization), whereas no-scaling is preferred in other cases (e.g. with L2 regularization).

See also [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_scale_c.html).